# Update the records from JSON string in apex

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, trigger, lightning-web-components, json

I have a JSON string in the format

`'{"key1":{"Field1__c":"false", "Field2__c":"false","Id":"XXXXXXXXXX909"}}'`

I need to update the record corresponding to "key1".

To achieve that I tried the below code:

```
public void updateRecords(String jsonString){

  Map<String,Object> deserializedJSON = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUnTyped(jsonString);

 SObject sObj = (sObject)deserializedJSON.get('key1');
 update sObj;


}
```

But doing this I am getting the below error:
`System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type Map<String,ANY> to SObject`

Then I changed my code to:

```
public void updateRecords(String jsonString){

  Map<String,Object> deserializedJSON = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUnTyped(jsonString);

 Map<String,SObject> sObj = (Map<String,sObject>)deserializedJSON.get('key1');
 update sObj;


}
```

After doing this I am getting the error:`System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type Map<String,ANY> to Map<String,SObject>`

Any suggestions how can I update any sObject record provided in JSON string?

Comment: Yea I checked, in my use case, I need to convert the Object from Map<String,Object> to sObject, so that I can update the record. But the conversion of Object to sObject is not happening..!

Comment: You can't convert it to sObject via a cast. The referenced answer shows how to extract elements from the Map without a sObject.